# Python 2.7 : List to Dict

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a list like this :

```
['Wi-Fi', '10.0.10.22', '255.255.0.0', '34-F3-9A-4C-D0-C4', 'VMware Network Adapter VMnet1', '192.168.10.111', '255.255.255.0', '00-50-56-C0-00-01', 'Loopback Pseudo-Interface 1', '127.0.0.1', '255.0.0.0', '00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0']
```

How can i convert it to dictionary like below :

```
{'1' : ['Wi-Fi', '10.0.10.22', '255.255.0.0', '34-F3-9A-4C-D0-C4'], '2' : ['VMware Network Adapter VMnet1', '192.168.10.111', '255.255.255.0', '00-50-56-C0-00-01'], '3' : ['Loopback Pseudo-Interface 1', '127.0.0.1', '255.0.0.0', '00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0']}
```

Many thanks,
Quang

Comment: what separates them? The keywords or the length?

Comment: @AntonvBR I guess every four items get assigned to a new key

Comment: @usr2564301 that's not a related duplicate...

Comment: Guessing is not knowing!
@Quang: what have you tried so far? Also, you don't have a string, but a list....

Comment: @EV. Konis is right. separates 4 to be 1 group. Thanks all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inspired by the [grouper recipe in itertools documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes):

```
l = ['Wi-Fi', '10.0.10.22', '255.255.0.0', '34-F3-9A-4C-D0-C4', 
     'VMware Network Adapter VMnet1', '192.168.10.111', '255.255.255.0', '00-50-56-C0-00-01', 
     'Loopback Pseudo-Interface 1', '127.0.0.1', '255.0.0.0', '00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0']

d = {i: sublist for i, sublist in enumerate(zip(*([iter(l)]*4)))}

print(d)

#{0: ('Wi-Fi', '10.0.10.22', '255.255.0.0', '34-F3-9A-4C-D0-C4'), 
# 1: ('VMware Network Adapter VMnet1', '192.168.10.111', '255.255.255.0', '00-50-56-C0-00-01'), 
# 2: ('Loopback Pseudo-Interface 1', '127.0.0.1', '255.0.0.0', '00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0')}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to split by 4 use this function for instance: [How do you split a list into evenly sized chunks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/312443)

```
l = ['Wi-Fi', '10.0.10.22', '255.255.0.0', '34-F3-9A-4C-D0-C4', 'VMware Network Adapter VMnet1', '192.168.10.111', '255.255.255.0', '00-50-56-C0-00-01', 'Loopback Pseudo-Interface 1', '127.0.0.1', '255.0.0.0', '00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0']

def chunks(l, n):
    """Yield successive n-sized chunks from l."""
    for i in range(0, len(l), n):
        yield l[i:i + n]

d = {ind:i for ind, i in enumerate(chunks(l, 4), 1)}
```

d returns:

```
{1: ['Wi-Fi', '10.0.10.22', '255.255.0.0', '34-F3-9A-4C-D0-C4'],
 2: ['VMware Network Adapter VMnet1',
  '192.168.10.111',
  '255.255.255.0',
  '00-50-56-C0-00-01'],
 3: ['Loopback Pseudo-Interface 1',
  '127.0.0.1',
  '255.0.0.0',
  '00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0']}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your rule is to split the list every four items, you can do it like so:

```
res = {i+1: n[i*4:4*(i+1)] for i in range(len(n)//4)}
```

which gives:

```
{1: ['Wi-Fi', '10.0.10.22', '255.255.0.0', '34-F3-9A-4C-D0-C4'], 
 2: ['VMware Network Adapter VMnet1', '192.168.10.111', '255.255.255.0', '00-50-56-C0-00-01'], 
 3: ['Loopback Pseudo-Interface 1', '127.0.0.1', '255.0.0.0', '00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0']}
```

---

Or if you are allergic to slicing:

```
n_i = iter(n)
res = {i+1: [next(n_i) for _ in range(4)] for i in range(len(n)//4)}
```

Comment: Your first solution is the most pythonic one. I don't think the second one improves anything

Comment: @sciroccorics Well, it doesn't.. The only excuse is *slicing-allergy*.

Comment: If someone suffers from slicing-allergy, maybe should he switch from Python to C ;-)

Answer (score 1):

```
input = ['Wi-Fi', '10.0.10.22', '255.255.0.0', '34-F3-9A-4C-D0-C4', 'VMware Network Adapter VMnet1', '192.168.10.111', '255.255.255.0', '00-50-56-C0-00-01', 'Loopback Pseudo-Interface 1', '127.0.0.1', '255.0.0.0', '00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0']

d = {}
for i in range(1,len(input)/3):
    d[i] = []

item = iter(input)
for i in range(len(d)):
    d[i+1] = [next(item) for x in range(len(d)+1)]
print d
```

The result as `d` would be `{1: ['Wi-Fi', '10.0.10.22', '255.255.0.0', '34-F3-9A-4C-D0-C4'], 2: ['VMware Network Adapter VMnet1', '192.168.10.111', '255.255.255.0', '00-50-56-C0-00-01'], 3: ['Loopback Pseudo-Interface 1', '127.0.0.1', '255.0.0.0', '00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0']}`

Comment: Thanks so much, you help me alot